# sending SMS with VBA

Tags: vba, sms

does anyone know if this is possible?

i was able to succesfully run hyperterminal and use it to send texts through my phone which is attached by USB.

anyone know how to do it in VBA?

Comment: I can provide C# code if you are interested, you can then transcode it into VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Public Sub SendSMS(ByVal Recipient As String, ByVal Message As String)
  Dim n As Integer

  n = FreeFile
  ' Change  the string below if using a different COM port or the port speed
  Open "COM1:9600,N,8,1" For Output As #n
  Print #n, "<SMS command string>"
  Close #n
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, I don't have a data cable for my phone handy so I can't try it!

Also, be aware that you may not have access to the serial port if you're not running as a privileged user.

Comment: As far as I know, it's always been possible in Microsoft Basics to read/write to the serial port like that

Answer (score 2):

If you know the other party e-mail address you can just send e-mail. Otherwise you will need a SMS gateway supplier which can deliver the messages to the correct networks.